# Div resize into divs %

Tags: html, css

My problem is that I'm trying to make a responsive template. I'm just making the header now.

First I will post here a code to get you the idea.

```
<div id="header_box">
  <div class="box">
  Content of box / Img
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  Content of box / Img
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  Content of box / Img
  </div>
</div>
```

The "header_box" is 100% width and thinking "box" is like 40%.

That means that since there are 3 "box" it will make 120%, is there a way so the "box" width automatically resize, to something like 30%, and if I add another "box" it makes 20%, or something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: have you considered using a responsive framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)? It will save you some trouble.

Comment: You can achieve that using JavaScript, which will allow you to add as many as box div and will fit in header_box div. Say suppose you have 2 div initially, but after you need 1 more div than you need not to change width, it will dynamically set and make a total 100%. If you want i will post the solution

Comment: @divy3993 Why use a JS-based solution when the flexbox specification is already quite widely supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your IDs should be unique, so in the example you've given you would be better to use classes instead (ie `class="box"`)

You can use flex and inline-flex in CSS to resize DIVs based on the screen width. I've attached a basic example here: http://jsfiddle.net/18e3cxd1/

```
.box {
    display:inline-flex;
    width:30%;
    border:solid 1px red;
}
```

This link offers some really good guidance for using flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header_box{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
.box{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    
    .box{
        display: table-caption;
    }    
    
}
```

```html
<div class="header_box">
    <div class="box">
        <p>Content of box / Img</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>Content of box / Img</p>
    </div>
     <div class="box">
        <p>Content of box / Img</p>
    </div>
</div>
```